# How to pass an object property as argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to write an custom react hook using TypeScript.
I have written simple helper function, which help me to check, if there is a such property in target object:

```
export function hasOwnProperty<X extends {}, Y extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: X,
  prop: Y,
): obj is X & Record<Y, unknown> {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);
}
```

And I'm trying to use it in my hook:

```
export const useAutocomplete = <T, Y extends PropertyKey>(data: Array<T>, property?: Y) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState<T[]>([]);

  const findResults = (element: T) => {
    if (property && hasOwnProperty(element, property)) {
      return String(element[property])
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(query.toLowerCase());
    }
    return String(element).toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
  };

  // ...other code

};
```

The problem is that I cant use methods like `toLowerCase()` and others even if I checking `if (typeof obj[property] === 'string')` it doesn't work. That is why I've decided to wrap my object in String and then I can access methods I need. But I think that It's not good solution and I want to ask what is the better way to figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out, how to make it really nice and flexible!
You may leave your comments If there is way to make it more clean, short and flexible.
In my solution I've used function overloading and Partial type:

```
export const useAutocomplete = <T>(
  data: Array<T>,
  property?: Partial<T>,
) => {
  // Declaring state

  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState<T[]>([]);

  // Creating type
  // for overloading function
  // it will allow us to accept
  // both simple string arrays
  // and sort by specific properties

  type Overloaded = {
    (element: string): boolean;
    (element: T): boolean;
  };

  // Simple helper function
  const getValue = (value: string, target: string) => value
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(target.toLowerCase());

  // Getting keys
  const getObjectKeys = (
    criteria: Partial<Cocktail>,
  ) => Object.keys(criteria) as (keyof Cocktail)[];

  const findResults: Overloaded = (element: any) => {
    if (property) {
      const propertyValue = getObjectKeys(property);
      return propertyValue.every((value) => getValue(element[value], query));
    }
    return getValue(element, query);
  };

  const handleSearch = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    setQuery(target.value);
    const searchResults = data.filter(findResults);
    setResults(searchResults);
  };

  return { handleSearch, results, query };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't know what is `T`

Explicitly tell typescript that your `T` is an object with string values

```
T extends { [key: string]: string}
```

full code

```
export const useAutocomplete = <T extends { [key: string]: string }, Y extends PropertyKey>(data: Array<T>, property?: Y) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState<T[]>([]);

  const findResults = (element: T) => {
    if (property && hasOwnProperty(element, property)) {
      return element[property]
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(query.toLowerCase());
    }
    return String(element).toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
  };

  // ...other code

};
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Medet! That's great, but it don't give me a flexibility. For example, If I'm not passing and property value(which is optional), i want to take an array of strings. But I cant do that because string !== { [key: string]: string }

Comment: If you trying to work with many types at once, you have to explicitly type cast, and this `element[property]` will always has to be type checked with `typeof element`